# If the image by $f$ of any compact is compact and the image of any connected set is connected, then $f$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness, connectedness

$ f : \mathbb R ^a \to \mathbb R ^b  $

If the image by $f$ of any compact is compact and the image of any connected set is connected, then $f$ is continuous.

(If only one of the two conditions is true, the result is false.)

Comment: Please show some effort rather than just dump a question on us and indicate how,nice,it would be to see several approaches.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I will try to find something by myself, but it seems quite difficult.

Comment: So, please, dont solve the entire problem immediately. Rather, I would like a hint.

Comment: what is the counterexample if you remove the assumption that the image of compact is compact?

Comment: in R->R : f(x) = sin(1/x)  with f(0) = 0. I'm thinking about a general counter-example. Maybe it is possible to use this function as coordinated applications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserving compactness and connectedness implies continuity for functions between locally connected, locally compact spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259833/preserving-compactness-and-connectedness-implies-continuity-for-functions-betwee)

Comment: Wow this is true, see http://www.renyi.hu/~soukup/setop/conti/conti.pdf

Comment: "Compact" alone is insufficient for continuity . Example: Let $0\ne v\in \Bbb R^n .$ For $m\in \Bbb N$ let $f(v/m)=v/m.$  For $u\in \Bbb R^n$ \ $\{v/m: m\in \Bbb N\}$  let $ f(u)=0.$

Comment: Or take f such that 0 -> 0 and others points -> a certain point different from 0